# How to connect VMs with private IPs owned by different users

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I want connect VMs with private IPs owned by different users. I tried SSH between the machines but private IPs are not reachable. Public IPs are working. Bothe users are located into the same AD-1 zone.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use private IPs and not public IP ? You will not be able to directly ssh using private IPs. You either need to use a jump server or bastion to achieve that. Please consider using OCI Bastion service. https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Bastion/Concepts/bastionoverview.htm.

Comment: I will need to have ports open 6443, 2379, 2380, 2380, 8080, 80, 22. Can I have all these ports open between VMs with private IPs using Bastion service?